# Associative Array with different key length

Tags: associative-array

I have a question about associative array.
Is it possible to have an associative array in which strings with different lengths used as keys?

Comment: Yes. Depending on the language.

Comment: In what language?   In C++ with `map<string, object>`, yes.  In Perl with hashes, yes.  I think in most languages the answer is yes.

Comment: In what language? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array for an overview.

Answer (score 0):

In all the languages I'm aware of, it's allowed. IMHO, it would be an incredibly stupid way to design a language if it didn't allow this.

Are you having a problem with your program that you think is because of different key lengths?